# how to build asp.net mvc application with single assembly dll

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dll, .net-assembly, publishing

A.O.A
    I have a web application in Asp.net MVC which has 2 my own created Assemblies and 2 other classes. The problem is that I want to create just 2 dlls each for my assembly but it creates for my project and other 2.

When I publish it, it creates
    EduSoft.Data.dll
    EduSoft.Helpers.dll
    MvcUi.dll
    NPoco.dll
    Newtonsoft.Json.dll

and I want all this in two only
EduSoft.Data.dll
EduSoft.Helpers.dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling I found the Answer .I solved it as
After publishing my web app(ASP.net MVC) I merged all my Dll's file into single dll By using ILMerge(By MS) and this blog showed me the write  command syntax.[ILMerg Command](http://martycodes.blogspot.com/2011/05/c-ilmerge.html)

Comment: I had done the same but getting the following error:Compiler Error Message: CS0234:

The type or namespace name 'Helpers' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'

(are you missing an assembly reference?)  How did you not get that error?

Answer (score 0):

This is what .net framework is all about!!

3rd party DLLS/Projects are treated as different from current project, and this is absolutely perfect.
Please don't try to think out of box in this case.

If you want single DLL, decompile all code from 3rd party tool, put it in your project (it's a security breach though)